# try catch vs promise chaining mechanism for error handing which one offers more flexibility?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I have a register controller that uses `try {} catch(e) {}` mechanism to me its a pretty decent ad-hoc mechanism for error but overall is it better switching to promises as i think promises offer more granuler error handling mechanisms, so below is my code as of now in my controller.

```
const registerNewUser = async (req, res) => {
  /*
     code here for extracting info from req
  */
  try {
    const users_data = await users.create_new_user({
      email,
      crypted_pwd,
      salt,
      first_name,
      phone_code,
    });

    const { id: user_id, first_name: user_first_name } = users_data;

    const customer_data = await customers.create_new_customer({
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
    });

    const {
      tenant_id,
      id: customer_id,
    } = customer_data;

    await clearCartFromRedis(merchant_canonical_name, req.token);

    signUpWelcomeMailer(merchant_canonical_name, req.token, user_id);

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      access_token: req.token,
      first_name: user_first_name,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    logger.log({ message: error.message, level: 'error' });
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

As you can see there are multiple things happening inside the try block. I.E. query to sequilize to `create_new_user` and `create_new_customer`, then, `clearCartFromRedis`, and then `signUpWelcomeMailer`. All three of these can throw different types of errors and yet i've handled them in one single `catch` block inside which i have the following statement.

```
return res.status(500).send(error.message);
```

So now my question is would it have been better to handle this in a promise chain using `then()` and `catch()` ? so say refactor the above to something like

```
customers.create_new_customer({
  first_name,
  last_name,
  email,
}).then(data => {
  const obj = { tenant_id: data.tenant_id, id: data.customer_id, merchant_canonical_name: data.merchant_canonical_name }
  return obj
}).then((obj) => { 
  clearCartFromRedis()
    .catch(() => { throw new Error('Could not clear cache') })
}).then(() => {
  signUpWelcomeMailer(merchant_canonical_name, req.token, user_id)
    .catch(() => { throw new Error('Error encountered while sending the email') })
}).catch(error => res.sendStatus(500))
```

So as you can see there is individual error handing as as well as a global catch block in the end. My question is in my use case is a global `try ... catch` better or the promise chaining mechanism ?

P.S. there is a similar question asked **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941655/how-do-i-handle-an-error-and-then-immediately-break-out-of-a-promise-chain/51941777#51941777)**, but this question pertains more towards `try .. catch` vs `promise chaining mechanism`.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await

Comment: You can combine `.catch()` calls (for fine-grained error handling) with `await` syntax (for simple sequential code) just fine, it's not either-or.

Comment: @Bergi you mean roughly speaking add the chaining inside a `try ..catch`, and let the global error handling be handled by try catch ?

Comment: Yes - incidentally I wrote [an answer demonstrating this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70415855/1048572) just yesterday. Although probably the "global error handling" would usually happen outside of the function, you'd just let the exceptions propagate upwards

Comment: @Bergi, thanks a ton , that kidda helps , so i'am assuming the only thing missing in my 1st code block (where i'am already using `await`) is the `catch` part. Also when u say  `let the exceptions propagate upwards` you mean something like `throw Error` inside the catch block and then the error is handled in a global `app.use(err => if(error) {return res.sendStatus(500)})` , did i get that somewhat right ? sorry for being a bit too inquisitive :P

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You rarely can really *handle* an exception, where not returning a result is ok (or maybe where you can return a fallback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `try... catch` is useful to catch mostly `expected` errors (when you need to return some 4xxx error with additional info or even 200 with a business logic error code or something like that) rather than some unexpected errors that should lead to 500 HTTP errors. That said you need a global handler for all non-catched/unexpected errors that will log these errors and send the 500 error to a client.

**global error handler**

```js
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    logger.error(err)

    res.status(500).send('Unexpected error')
  })
```

**try/catch with an explicit transaction**

```js
const registerNewUser = async (req, res) => {
  /*
     code here for extracting info from req
  */
  // here is some call to create a transaction in a DB
  // it varies depending on a type of DB and a package you use to communicate with it
  // we need to create a transaction BEFORE try/catch block
  const transaction = await createTransaction();
  try {
    // we need to pass transaction to every method that modifies data in DB
    // also depends on how to pass a transaction to underlying DB package methods
    const users_data = await users.create_new_user({
      email,
      crypted_pwd,
      salt,
      first_name,
      phone_code,
    }, transaction);

    const { id: user_id, first_name: user_first_name } = users_data;

    // we need to pass transaction to every method that modifies data in DB
    const customer_data = await customers.create_new_customer({
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
    }, transaction);

    const {
      tenant_id,
      id: customer_id,
    } = customer_data;

    await clearCartFromRedis(merchant_canonical_name, req.token);

    signUpWelcomeMailer(merchant_canonical_name, req.token, user_id);

    // here we need to commit the transaction before we exit from this handler
    await transaction.commit();

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      access_token: req.token,
      first_name: user_first_name,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // here we need to rollback the transaction before we exit from this handler
    await transaction.rollback();
    logger.log({ message: error.message, level: 'error' });
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

Secondly, in your case of several operations against some DB you clearly need to use a **transaction mechanism** to keep data consistent. Usually, it requires creating an explicit transaction and passing it to each query that should be executed as a one atomic operation that either executes correctly (then you need to commit a transaction) or fails (then you need to rollback a transaction). For that, you can use `try...catch` to be able to commit or rollback a transaction at the end of a batch of operations.

Comment: thank you 2nd part of you're answer is really insightful. first part confuses more , in the example i've provided how would `try...catch` be better than promise chain mechanism ? can you give an example ?

Comment: Added to the answer

Comment: thanks alot for the trouble and espically the additional point that you mentioned :D