# JavaScript: differences between async error handling with async/await and then/catch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

Just wanted to preemptively say that I am familiar with async/await and promises in JavaScript so no need to link me to some MDN pages for that.

I have a function to fetch user details and display it on the UI.

```js
async function someHttpCall() {
  throw 'someHttpCall error'
}
async function fetchUserDetails() {
  throw 'fetchUserDetails error'
}

function displayUserDetails(userDetails) {
  console.log('userDetails:', userDetails)
}

async function fetchUser() {
  try {
    const user = await someHttpCall()
    try {
      const details = await fetchUserDetails(user)
      returndisplayUserDetails(details)
    } catch (fetchUserDetailsError) {
      console.log('fetching user error', fetchUserDetailsError)
    }
  } catch (someHttpCallError) {
    console.log('networking error:', someHttpCallError)
  }
}
```

It first makes HTTP call via `someHttpCall` and if it succeeds then it proceeds to `fetchUserDetails` and it that succeeds as well then we display the details on Ui via `returndisplayUserDetails`.

If `someHttpCall` failed, we will stop and not make `fetchUserDetails` call. In other words,  we want to separate the error handling for `someHttpCall` and it’s data handling from `fetchUserDetails`

The function I wrote is with nested `try catch` blocks which doesn't scale well if the nesting becomes deep and I was trying to rewrite it for better readability using plain `then` and `catch`

This was my first atttempt

```js
function fetchUser2() {
  someHttpCall()
    .then(
      (user) => fetchUserDetails(user),
      (someHttpCallError) => {
        console.log('networking error:', someHttpCallError)
      }
    )
    .then(
      (details) => {
        displayUserDetails(details)
      }, //
      (fetchUserDetailsError) => {
        console.log('fetching user error', fetchUserDetailsError)
      }
    )
}
```

The problem with this is that the second `then` will run i.e. `displayUserDetails` even with `someHttpCall` failing. To avoid this I had to make the previous `.catch` blocks throw

so this is the updated version

```js
function fetchUser2() {
  someHttpCall()
    .then(
      (user) => fetchUserDetails(user),
      (someHttpCallError) => {
        console.log('networking error:', someHttpCallError)
        throw someHttpCallError
      }
    )
    .then(
      (details) => {
        displayUserDetails(details)
      }, //
      (fetchUserDetailsError) => {
        console.log('fetching user error', fetchUserDetailsError)
      }
    )
}
```

However now the second catch will get called as a result of the throw. So when the `someHttpCall` failed, after we handled the `someHttpCallError` error, we would enter this block `(fetchUserDetailsError) => { console.log('fetching user error', fetchUserDetailsError) }` which is not good since `fetchUserDetails` never gets called so we shouldn't need to handle `fetchUserDetailsError` (I know `someHttpCallError` became `fetchUserDetailsError` in this case)

I can add some conditional checks in there to distinguish the two errors but it seems less ideal. So I am wondering how I can improve this by using `.then` and `.catch` to achieve the same goal here.

Comment: To do it correctly, you'd need to nest things again and you'd be back where you started. Nesting the exception handling _is_ the most logical way... If you'd want to improve readability you could put the inner part into a separate function instead... Or, if you could put the second try/catch block below the first instead of putting it inside of it, but then you'd need to declare some variables outside of it with `let`.

Comment: Throw different error instances, then split up the error handling with `if (error instanceof ErrorClass1)`

Comment: Was `returndisplayUserDetails(details)` meant to be `return displayUserDetails(details)`? It looks like your `.then()` chains are missing this `return` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering how I can improve this by using `.then` and `.catch` to achieve the same goal here

You don't get to avoid the nesting if you want to replicate the same behaviour:

```
function fetchUser2() {
  return someHttpCall().then(
    (user) => {
      return fetchUserDetails(user).then(
        (details) => {
          return displayUserDetails(details)
        },
        (fetchUserDetailsError) => {
          console.log('fetching user error', fetchUserDetailsError)
        }
      )
    },
    (someHttpCallError) => {
      console.log('networking error:', someHttpCallError)
      throw someHttpCallError
    }
  )
}
```

(The exact equivalent to `try`/`catch` would use [`.then(…).catch(…)` instead of `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572), but [you might not actually want that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await).)

> The function I wrote is [nested] which doesn't scale well if the nesting becomes deep and I was trying to rewrite it for better readability […]

For that, I would recommend to combine `await` with `.catch()`:

```
async function fetchUser() {
  try {
    const user = await someHttpCall().catch(someHttpCallError => {
      throw new Error('networking error', {cause: someHttpCallError});
    });
    const details = await fetchUserDetails(user).catch(fetchUserDetailsError => {
      throw new Error('fetching user error', {cause: fetchUserDetailsError});
    });
    return displayUserDetails(details);
  } catch (someError) {
    console.log(someError.message, someError.cause);
  }
}
```

(The `cause` option for `Error` is still quite new, you might need a polyfill for that)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! This totally makes sense to me! Just one quick question - I find a lot of people don't like `try catch` blocks so they prefer `then.catch` over `async await`. Do you think there is anything suboptimal with `try catch`?

Comment: @Joji No, it's entirely up to preference.

Answer (score 2):

> I can add some conditional checks in there to distinguish the two errors but it seems less ideal.

Actually, that sounds like an ideal situation. That means that you don't have to nest any `try / catch` blocks which could make you code a lot more readable. This is one of the things that `async / await` is meant to solve.

A solution could be is to create custom errors by extending the [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) interface to be able to determine how and where the error occurs.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(name, ...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

Throw your errors within the functions that correspond with the error.

```
async function someHttpCall() {
  throw new CustomError('HttpCallError', 'someHttpCall error');
}

async function fetchUserDetails(user) {
  throw new CustomError('UserDetailsError', 'fetchUserDetails error')
}
```

Now you can control your error flow by checking the `name` property on the error to differentiate your errors.

```
async function fetchUser() {
  try {
    const user = await someHttpCall()
    const details = await fetchUserDetails(user)
    return displayUserDetails(details)
  } catch (error) {
    switch(error.name) {
      case 'HttpCallError':
        console.log('Networking error:', error)
        break

      case 'UserDetailsError':
        console.log('Fetching user error', error)
        break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 From me because this also follows semantics similar to try-catch in typed languages where you can have multiple catch blocks

Answer (score 0):

I've been inspired by [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)'s [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) type (which forces you to handle every potential error along the way).

So what I do is handle exceptions in every individual function, and never allow one to throw, instead returning either an Error (if something went wrong) or the desired return value (if no exception occurred). Here's an example of how I do it (comments included):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true#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-b8iT-WwAIoqjiRAsCSx7ABhUYF3QdxiVgPENWWIlsHVGT3jaPDyMtWhTzYYgSgbUY4IQ1AcDkejK2rFc8IbQiohIkSuHIpSaMuOjS37MwmJYsdzXY6dZ24hcl1sfi1yYITiVS3cex7KB0FoUZ3EYGdkCHc83nXQcTCaUAACsZzMHgmnQFA4D8Gc+GldB1BEaBbH3WQCVIfIetkohshKJcADVLlU4gNI-Hov1Qn8jJjJAHFM5SQOhYZTnIflhkwGqzG8aI2DaR0zCvU4+GO9DX0qG5QAUJKKl03gYWGL1SXJHlKm8CGFEKtoTWWAADbwcdBDgDnh2Eq3hBSMpUx8X3U1GcHRsBofSszjBhe5hh4pcqioKU3uGUYyaKEoUZ59Jhnue41tgDaMC294cCwI5UJKGBWwAdTww7phBmmztAC7iCuzxvD5GEPLmBF0DcX7-pePbIC1+odbbWmGct0F7obKIeRhQUtM+SlhWuJ73oUdhOCkChKTZmFUE0dBzawKQtC4LBeCD1JIbAeUPcp0AF2lRAjEIJBZHuIA)

> If you aren't familiar with TypeScript, you can see the JavaScript-only version of the following code (with no type information) at the TypeScript Playground link above (on the right side of the page).

```ts
// This is the code in my exception-handling utility module:
// exception-utils.ts

export type Result <T = void, E extends Error = Error> = T | E;

export function getError (value: unknown): Error {
  return value instanceof Error ? value : new Error(String(value));
}

export function isError <T>(value: T): value is T & Error {
  return value instanceof Error;
}

export function assertNotError <T>(value: T): asserts value is Exclude<T, Error> {
  if (value instanceof Error) throw value;
}
```

```ts
// This is how to use it:
// main.ts

import {assertNotError, getError, isError, type Result} from './exception-utils.ts';

/** 
 * Returns either Error or string ID,
 * but won't throw because it catches exceptions internally
 */
declare function getStringFromAPI1 (): Promise<Result<string>>;

/** 
 * Requires ID from API1. Returns either Error or final number value,
 * but won't throw because it catches exceptions internally
 */
declare function getNumberFromAPI2 (id: string): Promise<Result<number>>;

/**
 * Create version of second function with no parameter required:
 * Returns either Error or final number value,
 * but won't throw because it catches exceptions internally
 * 
 * The previous two functions work just like this, using the utilities
 */
async function fetchValueFromAPI2 (): Promise<Result<number>> {
  try {
    const id = await getStringFromAPI1(); // Error or string
    assertNotError(id); // throws if `id` is an Error
    return getNumberFromAPI2(id); // Error or number
  }
  catch (ex) {
    return getError(ex);
  }
}

async function doSomethingWithValueFromAPI2 (): Promise<void> {
  const value = await fetchValueFromAPI2(); // value is number or Error
  if (isError(value)) {
    // handle error
  }
  else console.log(value); // value is number at this point
}
```